# Iterate over column values in a dataframe - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this

| emp_id | emp_role | mgr_id | mgr_role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | AP | 112 | SP |
| 112 | SP | 116 | DP |
| 114 | LP | 115 | DP |

For each employee, I need to print the emp_role, his mgr_id and mgr_role

I have tried this

```
for id in df['emp_id']:
    print(id + 'with role' + df['emp_role'] + 'is reporting to' + df['mgr_id'] + 'with role' + df['mgr_role']
```

This prints the output multiple times but i need to print it exactly once. Please help to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Expected output:

```
111 with role AP is reporting to 112 with role SP
112 with role SP is reporting to 116 with role DP
114 with role LP is reporting to 115 with role DP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are really close to your approach. Depending on how you defined your table in Python, you can use print with format.

```
table = [    [111, "AP", 112, "SP"],
    [112, "SP", 116, "DP"],
    [114, "LP", 115, "DP"]
]

for row in table:
  emp_id, emp_role, mgr_id, mgr_role = row
  print("{} with role {} is reporting to {} with role {}".format(emp_id, emp_role, mgr_id, mgr_role))
```

Comment: Here's a Trinket: https://trinket.io/python3/7d204527f9